# Ubuntu Java JDK artifact is missing

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu 16.10 and JDK 1.8.0 I'm getting this while a maven build (3.3.9):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (check) on project parent: Execution check of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

JAVA_HOME is set to this path. What might cause that?

Comment: What exactly is your JAVA_HOME set to?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using OpenJdk instead of OracleJDK you have different JVM enviroment, thus com.sun packages may not be available in your system.

You may verify this by trying to build project on system with OracleJdk.

Comment: I have com.sun packages in my OpenJava.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this caused by environement variable, try this:

```
export JAVA_HOME =/~.../dirictoryOfYourJDK
export M2_HOME =/~.../dirictoryOfYourMaven
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin
```

i hope that help you